# How to run one test inside a nested class with maven?

Tags: maven, junit

JUnit Example code:

```
class OuterClass {

   @Nested
   class InnerClass {

      @Test
      void test() {
      }
   }
}
```

This command: `mvn test -Dtest=OuterClass*` runs all tests in the OuterClass.

This command: `mvn test -Dtest=OuterClass$InnerClass*` runs all tests in the InnerClass.

This command: `mvn test -Dtest=OuterClass$InnerClass#test` runs no tests. How can I run only this test method?

Comment: Take care of the `$` on the command line...please try to use `\$`... ? Apart from that why not running your unit tests from within your IDE...

Comment: Your advice worked. Thank you.